# Python PyGTK. What's this component?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I'm trying to write a simple GTD-style todo list app with python and gtk to learn python.  I want a container that can select an individual list from a lot of choices.  It would be something like the list of notebooks area in tomboy.  Not a combobox.

As you can probably tell I'm a beginner and the terminology is probably off.

Can you please tell me what it is I'm looking for and an overview of how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a listbox, unless you're describing something more complex than I'm picturing.

Wikipedia has a [list of GUI widgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUI_widget#List_of_common_generic_widgets) that you may find informative.

Comment: GTK+ has its own [widget gallery](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/ch02.html), with pictures and links to their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a widget to filter a large collection into multiple subsets / views?

I would guess you have to implement this yourself - a list of options on the left and filtered results on the right, I don't know of any existing (gtk) widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Notebooks' button in Tomboy is a `gtk.MenuToolItem` with a `gtk.Menu` containing `gtk.RadioMenuItem`s.

Here is a short example:

```
import gtk

window = gtk.Window()
box = gtk.VBox()
toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
toolbutton = gtk.MenuToolButton(gtk.STOCK_FLOPPY)
menu = gtk.Menu()
labels = ['Disk 1', 'Disk 2', 'Disk 3']
items = [gtk.RadioMenuItem(label=l) for l in labels]

window.set_default_size(300, 300)
window.add(box)
box.pack_start(toolbar, expand=False, fill=True)
toolbar.insert(toolbutton, 0)
toolbutton.set_menu(menu)
for item in items:
    if item is not items[0]:
        item.set_group(items[0])
    item.show()
    menu.append(item)

window.show_all()
window.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)
gtk.main()
```